# Probability of two people picking balls from an infinite pile but have equal winning chances

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

So i was given this question

There is an unlimited pile of balls. They are numbered by 1, 2, 3, . . ..
Two players A and B randomly select one ball each and check their number. The
winner is the player who picked the lowest numbered ball. Let us consider the
chances of winning of player A. Assume that player A picked a ball with number k.
As there is a finite number of balls numbered lower than k and unlimited number
of balls with larger numbers, then we can conclude that the chance of player A
winning is much more likely than loosing. However, the same argument works for
the player B. Thus, both players have advantage over the other player. How is it
possible?

I have absolutely no clue on how to go about this. I have never seen a question like this in my textbook so I don't know how to start it.

Comment: There is no probability distribution on the natural numbers that assigns equal probability to all of them.

Comment: @AndréNicolas can you break that down what you mean by that. So does that mean this can't be solved because there in unlimited pile of balls?

Comment: Not to mention that if the players *knew* that the lowest number wins then they would hardly use a very random distribution to pick their numbers ...

Comment: To solve the problem, we need to know the probability distribution of A's pick, also of B's pick. Your informal argument tacitly assumes all numbers are equally likely. There is no probability distribution on the natural numbers in which all natural numbers are equally likely.

Comment: It could just assume $\forall k (P(n>k)>P(n\leq k))$, that is impossible anyways

Comment: This is similar to the primitive version of the two envelopes paradox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_envelopes_problem